# getting an excel extension because the old extension is no longer working when downloaded

Tags: c#, excel, visual-studio

I have a code similar to this below

```
using(webclient wc = new WebClient())
{
string fileinfoname = "test_one";
string pathinfo = @"C:\testfolderinfo" + fileinfoname + ".xlsx";

wc.downloadFile("www.testurl.com/report", pathinfo);

}
```

I am currently experiencing a situation where the file is being downloaded but when I try to utilize excel to open the file, it gives the message

"Excel cannot open the file test_one because the file format or file extension is not valid. Verify that the file has not been corrupted and that the file extension matches the format of the file"

This just started happening, hence how do i get an actual excel extension for excel 2007 and above to replace it above.

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

There is something wrong with your code itself, the correct code should be as follows:

```
using (WebClient wc = new WebClient())
{
    string fileinfoname = "test_one";
    string pathinfo = Path.Combine("C:\testfolderinfo\", fileinfoname, ".xlsx");
 
    wc.DownloadFile("www.testurl.com/report", pathinfo);
 
}
```

If you have already downloaded the file, then your C# code at runtime should be fine. It may be that the format was wrong when you posted the post. You can directly read the content below.

First, please confirm whether your target website file is in xlsx format. If it is not a xlsx format file, please change the suffix name of pathinfo to the corresponding suffix name of the target file. For example, your target file is report.xlsx, usually the download link is `www.testurl.com/report.xlsx`. You can also download this file in your browser and open it to see what type of file it is.

Note that while both XLS and XLSX are file formats for Microsoft Spreadsheets, they have different file extensions, .xls and .xlsx respectively. XLS is the default file format from Excel 97 to Excel 2003, while XLSX is the default file format for Excel 2007 and later.

**Second update:**

Do you have Protected View in your Excel software? I can find it here by following steps:

File => Options => Trust Center => Trust Center Settings => Protected View

Please uncheck the following three options:

[image]

Comment: Hi I have confirmed that the target file is SpreadsheetML because I can manually download the file and use microsoft excel to open the file, however if I run my code and use it to download it, i am not able to open it with microsoft excel. it gives the message ""Excel cannot open the file test_one because the file format or file extension is not valid. Verify that the file has not been corrupted and that the file extension matches the format of the file"

Comment: I updated my excel settings and unfortunately that didn't work either

Comment: Hi, I just realized the issue is with the SOAP webservice, can someone please guide me on how to call a http SOAP request, get an http SOAP response as a excel, all help is appreciated

Comment: @Nap Hello, if you use the original WebClient code to download the file extension and change it to .zip, can it be opened correctly?